# Android Facebook Integration don't need login

Tags: android, facebook

If i don not want to use facebook login only share text + images from my app to facebook profile of the app user..do i need to go through the keyhash stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to register your app on facebook platform before your app can post/share. Once you register your identity will be confirmed and you'll be given unique id for your app.
Later you need to use facebook login to get active access_token, which is must to share your text+images.